# file_exists command gives false result even if file is there

Tags: php, file

In PHP function

```
$file_name = 'http://hoorz.com:80/media/review_images/1_1.jpg';

file_exists($file_name)
```

gives false result even if file is already there on the server.
My file permissions are:

```
-rw-r--r--
```

Directory permission:

```
drwxr-xr-x
```

What could be the reason? What could be the required file permission for this function?

Comment: The path in `$file_name` is wrong.

Comment: Do any of the "Related" questions and answers _(on the right side of this page)_ help?

Comment: path name is right. I checked it from my browser.

Comment: Send your files structure and the value of $file_name please

Comment: The permissions on the file have nothing to do with whether PHP can determine if the file exists - PHP needs to read the directory to determine that - what are the permissions *and ownership* of the directory?

Answer (score 0):

I always pass the directory path to `file_exists`. Maybe that could be an alternative for you.

> $file_name = 'home/hoorza/public_html/media/review_images/1_1.jpg';